# Locating first span element using Css-Selector (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

The tested application has been changed and I found myself in a tricky situation.
Given the following part of code:

```
<span class="some some-locator">
   <span>Some dummy text</span>
   <span>Some stacktrace text</span>
</span>
```

I tried this locator: `span.some.some-locator`

The problem is, it gives back two span however I need the first one, "some dummy text" only. "Some stacktrace text" is not necessary for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
span.some.some-locator > span:first-of-type {
  // styles goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the :nth-child selector

For your case should something like this:

```
span.some.some-locator > span:nth-child(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following,

```
//span[contains(text(),'Some dummy text')]
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it can be used with selenium properly, handling as a text is easy. But others are good as well.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work at different time, because the text can be similar.

Comment: If your text is different every time and ifs its dynamic, you can also pass variable in which you are looking for value, 
 like wise, //span[contains(text(),'"+variable name +"')]